# Adding 'react-native-camera' dependency Breaks the Project

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

I have a project that includes a few native modules. When I try to integrate the 'react-native-camera' the projects fails to build. Is there any option that I can localize all the dependencies of react-native-camera without affecting the others? Or is there any workaround for this?

settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-camera'
project(':react-native-camera').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,'../node_modules/react-native-camera/android')
```

Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
           url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // for ssl pinning module
    }
}
```

app build.gradle

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adl.dialog.bizcare"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 8
        versionName "0.0.6.08"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86-64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86-64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }


}


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

    implementation project(':react-native-ssl-pinning')

      // Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"


    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'

    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-sms-retriever')

    //implementation project(':react-native-camera')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Have you installed it automatically, not manually?

Comment: @hong develop, I've added the dependencies manually.

Comment: Why don't you use a link?